# Why http.conf Variations

Tags: linux

What is it that determines the contents of a httpd.conf file in a fresh Apache install?

I ask because a few months ago I installed one server and the httpd.conf file was as long as a book, however for the server I installed last night it's only about 1/5 as long and so is missing several configuration examples/defaults.

Comment: That depends on how you're installing apache.

Comment: @EEAA The most recent was installed via yum (CentOS 7) and the prior I'm almost sure was also via yum (CentOS 6.5).

Comment: Whoever built the package determines what is in the config files provided by the package. You're essentially at the whim of the maintainer.

Comment: IIRC some configuration was simplified in Apache 2.4 (as a result, the default configuration in Ubuntu is shorter). I don't recall what changed, exactly.

Comment: Also to be noted to whoever approved this migration: Apache works fine on Windows too.